# Need to print name instead of id in vue.js frontend and Laravel backend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, laravel-8

Here is my CategoryController.php code...

```
public function name($id) {
    $f = Category::findOrFail($id);
    $nm = $f->name;
    return $nm;
}
```

Here is my router.

```
Route::get('/category/{id}', [CategoryController::class, 'name']);
```

In vue.js I defined this in method,

```
async getCategoryName($id){
            await this.callApi('get','/category/' + $id)
            .then(response => {
                this.name = response.data.name
                return this.name;
            });
    }
```

In the table, I need to get category name instead of category id. from URL I get category name but It shows that [object promise]

```
                    <table class="_table">
                            <!-- TABLE TITLE -->
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Category Name</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Created At</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                            <!-- TABLE TITLE -->

                            <!-- ITEMS -->
                        <tr v-for="(tag, i) in tags" :key="i" if="tags.length">
                            <td>{{tag.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{getCategoryName(tag.categoryId)}}</td>
                            <td class="_table_name">{{tag.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{tag.created_at}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <Button type="info" size="small" @click="showEditModal(tag, i)">Edit</Button>
                                <Button type="error" size="small" @click="showDeletingModal(tag, i)" :loading="tag.isDeleting">Delete</Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behaviour of vue.js, why don't you add the category name in your controller instead of loading it server side, your approach is not good performance wise.

In your controller where you get the view you will have something like: `$tags = Tag::all()`
You can simply load in each categroy: `$tags = Tag::with('category')->get()`

In your vue app you can then simply access the name like: `tag.category.name`

Comment: async getCategoryName($id){
    await this.callApi('get','/category/' + $id)
    .then(response => {
     this.name = response.data.name
     return this.name;
    });
  }

Comment: sorry this is my method

Comment: I need to replace subcategory Id with category name. So by passing subcategory table categoryId I took the category name. I returned it in the method. But it isn't working. Could please help me?

Comment: Yes, this call is not necessary and not good for your performance, you can load the category name with all other data, can you show your controller method? (not the one for the api request, the one where you get the view and everything)

Comment: @YasithSFonseka I'm going to interject and say, this is not a platform where we do your work for you. If you are incapable of doing this task, then you either need to learn more (read some docs), or go to a site like [Fiverr](https://www.fiverr.com) or [Freelancer](https://www.freelancer.co.uk) and pay them to do it for you.